# Azure Devops bulk create Tasks for every Product Backlog Item

Tags: azure-devops

I have 100 PBIs (let's say they're named 001-100) in Azure DevOps.
Every PBI should have clones of Tasks A and B as child link.
How can I assign these underlying tasks to all 100 PBIs in one action, without manually making duplicates of the tasks and assign them to all the PBIs?

I have tried creating a template from a PBI with already their childs A' en B' defined, but these child links are not carried through the template to another existing PBIs.

Prefered result in the backlog

```
FeatureX
  -001
    -A' 
    -B' 
  -002
    -A'
    -B'
  -003
    -A'
    -B'
etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I assign these underlying tasks to all 100 PBIs in one action, without manually making duplicates of the tasks and assign them to all the PBIs?

You can use the PowerShell script to create cloned work items and then link the new created work items to Product Backlog Items.

Here is a PowerShell example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/ORG/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
   "query": "SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType],  [System.State],[System.AreaPath],[System.Tags],[System.CommentCount],[System.ChangedDate] FROM workitems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'projectname' AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog item' ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC"
}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

ForEach ($workitemid in $response.workitems.id)
{
   echo $workitemid
   $witType="task"
   $url2= "https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/wit/workitems/`$$($witType)?api-version=6.0"
   $JSON2 = @'
  [
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }
]
'@
 $response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON2 -ContentType application/json-patch+json

 $ClonetaskAID= $response2.id

 $url3= "https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/wit/workitems/`$$($witType)?api-version=6.0"
   $JSON3 = @'
  [
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }
]
'@
 $response3 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url3 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON3 -ContentType application/json-patch+json

 $ClonetaskBID= $response3.id


   $url1 ="https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workitemid)?api-version=6.0"
   $JSON1 = "
   [
 
    {
    `"op`": `"add`",
    `"path`": `"/relations/-`",
    `"value`": {
      `"rel`": `"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward`",
      `"url`": `"https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/wit/workItems/$ClonetaskAID`"
    }
    },
   {
    `"op`": `"add`",
    `"path`": `"/relations/-`",
    `"value`": {
      `"rel`": `"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward`",
      `"url`": `"https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/wit/workItems/$ClonetaskBID`"
    }
    }

]
"
$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PATCH -Body $JSON1 -ContentType application/json-patch+json
}
```

You can use the WIQL Rest API: [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) to get all work items.

Then you can create the work items based on Task A and B. Rest API: [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)

Finally, you can link the work item to PBI. Rest API: [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)