# Why does Azure Devops create work-item return 404 page not found?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using the Azure DevOps API to create a new work item. However I get an error

`404 page not found`

Documentation: [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)

Things I've tried

1. Using postman and powershell (see screenshot and script below). [image]
2. In the json data I am populating only the required fields. The various values come from get API calls (e.g. get iterations).
3. Changed the API version (6.0, 5.1)
4. Included / excluded the project name in the URL
5. Created a new personal access token

Get calls work (e.g. get list of teams, projects, work item types)

Why the 404 error for post?

Below the powershell script

```
$url= "https://dev.azure.com/my-org/my-project/_apis/wit/workitems/$($witType)?api-version=6.0"
$JSON = @'
  [
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }    ,
{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/fields/System.IterationId",
  "from": null,
  "value": "e5c8d590-5283-4642-8262-716d083bc045"      
},
{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/fields/System.AreaId",
  "from": null,
  "value": "138233"      
},
{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/fields/System.State",
  "from": null,
  "value": "To Do"      
}
]
'@


Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json-patch+json
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue should be related to the Rest API URL.

When you run the Rest API in Postman, you need to add `$` before the work item type.

For example:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=6.0
```

When you use the PowerShell to run the Rest API, you need to modify the URL.

```
https://dev.azure.com/my-org/my-project/_apis/wit/workitems/`$$($witType)?api-version=6.0
```

Here is an example:

```
$url= "https://dev.azure.com/my-org/my-project/_apis/wit/workitems/`$$($witType)?api-version=6.0"
$JSON = @'
  [
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }    ,
{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/fields/System.IterationId",
  "from": null,
  "value": "e5c8d590-5283-4642-8262-716d083bc045"      
},
{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/fields/System.AreaId",
  "from": null,
  "value": "138233"      
},
{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/fields/System.State",
  "from": null,
  "value": "To Do"      
}
]
'@


Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json-patch+json
```

Refer to this ticket: [Azure Devops bulk create Tasks for every Product Backlog Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73335298/azure-devops-bulk-create-tasks-for-every-product-backlog-item/73396799#73396799)